# Do not return email when "Users" based model is included in relational query

Tags: model, loopbackjs

I have model based on User model - Customer.
When i query this model directly it give error `"Authorization Required"`.
Which is desired.

But when i include Customer in query for Products (like `{"include":["customer"]}`) 
i get almost whole Customer model instance **with** email of user.

I'd like to hide email from anyone querying Products, and give only username and id of user.

I can remove data sent to client with operation hook or remote hook.

Is there a way to restrict data access from model.json or hooks are only method?

Comment: Have you tried adding the 'hidden' prop to Product.json?

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Hiddenproperties

Comment: @amuramoto : I believe 'protected' property suits this scenario better (see my answer). _"Authorization Required"_ suggests that there is some ACL on a Customer model (Maybe it's accessible for owner?). Your approach would hide affected properties for everyone. Maybe OP can elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide certain properties, when object is nested in a HTTP response of a related model, use [protected](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Protectedproperties) property in your [model definition](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file) file.

Example from a Loopback documentation:

*common/models/customer.json*

```
...
  "properties": {
    ...
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
...
   "protected": ["email"],
...
```

In case you want to apply ACL on related models, you need to specify them separately. See [Accessing related models](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Accessing+related+models) section of a LoopBack documentation.